# Xcode caching of previous project with same name?

Tags: xcode

I'm starting a project from scratch in `Xcode4` using the same name as a previous attempt at the project that this one replaces, saved in a different directory. So far all it has is the initial tab bar controller that `Xcode` set up for me; not a single line of added code on my part.  When I try to build and run it in the `iPhone 4.3 Simulator` it *crashes* complaining that it can't find files referenced in the old version that aren't even mentioned anywhere in the new code, i.e.:

```
2011-07-29 12:30:37.751 DFM Mobile[770:207] Could not load the "190-bank.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "Department-of-Family-Medicine.DFM-Mobile"
```

So somewhere it has cached information about the previous project.  I've deleted the old one from the simulator, and even emptied out:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/
```

I've deleted the cache in:

```
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Xcode
```

I've rebooted. Same problem. Any suggestions on where else it might be fooled into thinking it's running the old project instead of the new one?  I could start again with a new name and then rename it later, but want to avoid that hassle if there's a simple answer.

Addendum:  I'm seeing more "ghosts" of previous versions of a project.  I got around the above by using a different name for the new project and then renaming it.  But I'm now seeing artifacts of the previous project in the new one.  For instance, a button on the navigation bar that I used in the previous project that doesn't even exist in the new project (and uses a graphic that doesn't exist either) is showing up in the new version when I download it to the iPhone, but not in the iPhone simulator.  It's definitely the new version of the project in every other way, but has this one remnant that doesn't exist in the code.  So there's some kind of buggy caching of at least parts of the previous project going on.

Answer (score 4):

Also delete the folder in `Library/Developer/Xcode/Derived Data`, remove the app from the simulator and build again.